# Horiztonal Jscrollpane reverts to vertical in IE7

Tags: jquery, jscrollpane, jquery-jscrollpane

when i view my site : http://www.testtrack.tv/ in IE8's compatibility-mode the horizontal scrollpanes turn into vertical panes.  this is not the case with Kevin's demo site, so it must be something in my CSS.

i'm using the default css from jscrollpane's examples, with a couple of additions... i added white-space: nowrap.  this works great everywhere except IE7 even though i thought this was a supported property.

```
/* Styles specific to this particular page */
.scroll-pane  {
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    overflow: auto;
    white-space:nowrap;
}
.horizontal-only {
    height: auto;
    max-height: 200px;
}

.thumbWrapper {
    margin-right: 10px;
    height: 150px;
    position: relative;
    width: 145px;
    white-space: normal;
    display: inline-block;
    /*hack for IE7 to display as inline-block*/
    zoom: 1;
    *display:inline;
}
```

where the thumbWrapper class is wrapping up the image and its caption into a div.  might this be better as an li element?

my markup looks like this:

```
<div class="scrollWrapper">
<h2>Editor's Choice</h2>
<p>the TestTrack.Tv team’s pick of the hottest clips...</p>

<div id="cat-48" class="scroll-pane horizontal-only">           

<div class="thumbWrapper">
    <a href="http://www.testtrack.tv/fast-and-furious-5-movie-trailer/">
    <img src='http://www.testtrack.tv/wp-content/uploads/2011/04/0470.jpg' height='81' alt='thumb'/>
    </a>
    <br/><a href="http://www.testtrack.tv/fast-and-furious-5-movie-trailer/">Fast And Furious 5 &#8211; Movie Trailer</a>
</div>

<div class="thumbWrapper">
    <a href="http://www.testtrack.tv/danny-macaskill-way-back-home/">
    <img src='http://www.testtrack.tv/wp-content/uploads/2011/04/0159.jpg' height='81' alt='thumb'/>
    </a>
    <br/><a href="http://www.testtrack.tv/danny-macaskill-way-back-home/">Danny MacAskill &#8211; &#8220;Way Back Home&#8221;</a>
</div>

<div class="thumbWrapper">
    <a href="http://www.testtrack.tv/dakar-2011-carlos-sainz-red-bull-volkswagen-touareg/">
    <img src='http://www.testtrack.tv/wp-content/uploads/2011/04/0678.jpg' height='81' alt='thumb'/>
    </a>
    <br/><a href="http://www.testtrack.tv/dakar-2011-carlos-sainz-red-bull-volkswagen-touareg/">Dakar 2011 &#8211; Carlos Sainz &#8211; Red Bull Volkswagen Touareg</a>
</div>

<div class="thumbWrapper">
    <a href="http://www.testtrack.tv/porsche-959-vs-ferrari-f40-bbc-top-gear/">
    <img src='http://www.testtrack.tv/wp-content/uploads/2011/04/0645.jpg' height='81' alt='thumb'/></a>
    <br/><a href="http://www.testtrack.tv/porsche-959-vs-ferrari-f40-bbc-top-gear/">Porsche 959 vs ferrari F40 &#8211; BBC Top Gear</a>
</div>

</div><!--.scroll-pane-->
</div><!--.scrollWrapper-->
```

ultimately, i'm looking for a fix to make it display horizontally in IE7 like all the other browsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the answer turned out to be to not use a block-level DIV when i wanted the elements to behave as inline.  IE7 was not properly handling the inline-block declaration.  switch the "thumbWrapper" element to SPAN solved this for me.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than relying on nowrap I would suggest adding an element inside your scroll-pane and explicitly setting the width of it. As you say, a UL would be a good candidate. e.g.

```
<div id="cat-48" class="scroll-pane horizontal-only">      
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="http://www.testtrack.tv/fast-and-furious-5-movie-trailer/">
            <img src='http://www.testtrack.tv/wp-content/uploads/2011/04/0470.jpg' height='81' alt='thumb'/>
            </a>
            <br/><a href="http://www.testtrack.tv/fast-and-furious-5-movie-trailer/">Fast And Furious 5 &#8211; Movie Trailer</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="http://www.testtrack.tv/danny-macaskill-way-back-home/">
            <img src='http://www.testtrack.tv/wp-content/uploads/2011/04/0159.jpg' height='81' alt='thumb'/>
            </a>
            <br/><a href="http://www.testtrack.tv/danny-macaskill-way-back-home/">Danny MacAskill &#8211; &#8220;Way Back Home&#8221;</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="http://www.testtrack.tv/dakar-2011-carlos-sainz-red-bull-volkswagen-touareg/">
            <img src='http://www.testtrack.tv/wp-content/uploads/2011/04/0678.jpg' height='81' alt='thumb'/>
            </a>
            <br/><a href="http://www.testtrack.tv/dakar-2011-carlos-sainz-red-bull-volkswagen-touareg/">Dakar 2011 &#8211; Carlos Sainz &#8211; Red Bull Volkswagen Touareg</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="http://www.testtrack.tv/porsche-959-vs-ferrari-f40-bbc-top-gear/">
            <img src='http://www.testtrack.tv/wp-content/uploads/2011/04/0645.jpg' height='81' alt='thumb'/></a>
            <br/><a href="http://www.testtrack.tv/porsche-959-vs-ferrari-f40-bbc-top-gear/">Porsche 959 vs ferrari F40 &#8211; BBC Top Gear</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div><!--.scroll-pane-->
```

And then in the javascript:

```
$(function() {
    // Calculate the width of the contents
    var w = 0;
    $('.scroll-pane li').each(
        function()
        {
            w += $(this).outerWidth();
        }
    );
    // Set the width of the UL
    $('.scroll-pane>ul').css('width', w + 'px');
    // Initialise jScrollPane
    $('.scroll-pane').jScrollPane();
});
```

Of course, you'll also need some CSS to make the list behave like a set of inline elements. And you won't need some of the other CSS you had. So the complete CSS should look something like:

```
.scroll-pane  {
    width: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}
.scroll-pane ul
{
    height: 150px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.scroll-pane li
{
    float: left;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 10px 0 0;
    height: 150px;
    width: 145px; 
}
```

Comment: wow thank you for your very detailed answer!  i ended up solving this by not using a DIV as the wrapper... since IE7 was choking on making a block-level element behave an an inline element.  i switched to a SPAN (after a lot of hair pulling) and that worked.  i suspect using LIs like you do here would work for the same reason.

Comment: Actually, li's are still block level elements. But they are floated left in the example above. Combined with setting the width on the container this will cause them to lay out horizontally...